# Block PHP Functions in Sub Classes

Tags: php, class, function

Is it possible to block the visibility of functions from a parent class in sub classes?

```
class DB {
  function connect() {
    // connects to db
  }
}
class OtherClass extends DB {
  function readData() {
    // reads data
  }
}
class AnotherOtherClass extends OtherClass {
  function updateUser($username) {
    // add username
  }
}
```

If I were to write:

```
$cls1= new OtherClass();
$cls1->connect(); // want to allow this class to show

$cls2= new AnotherOtherClass();
$cls2->connect(); // do not want this class to show
$cls2->readData(); // want to allow this class to show
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you don't *actually* want `AnotherOtherClass` to extend `OtherClass`. Perhaps you want to consume / wrap / decorate `OtherClass` instead, eg

```
class AnotherOtherClass
{
    private $other;

    public function __construct(OtherClass $other)
    {
        $this->other = $other;
    }

    public function readData()
    {
        // proxy to OtherClass::readData()
        return $this->other->readData();
    }

    public function updateUser($username)
    {
        // add username
    }
}
```

You could also do this but it smells bad

```
class AnotherOtherClass extends OtherClass
{
    public function connect()
    {
        throw new BadMethodCallException('Not available in ' . __CLASS__);
    }
```

Comment: To take it a step further, I doubt the DB class should even be getting extended in the first place.

Comment: @Matthew without knowing what these classes actually do, it's hard to make a call on that

Comment: if i used the DB class to handle all the sql operations, then i could extend that class to perform CRUD operations for example? or would you just pass a DB class an an option into the CRUD class to perform database operations? how would you do it?

Comment: @Ourx I'd opt for the latter. You would pass the `DB` object as a dependency, the same way that the `OtherClass` object is a dependency for `AnotherOtherClass` in my answer